# How do I set up the simplest HTTP local server?

Tags: server, webserver, localhost, r, html

I use the [R Studio IDE](https://www.rstudio.com/) to do many things, one of which is to serve local websites utilizing the [blogdown package](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown) which is a fork of [hugo](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo). I write the code in *R Studio* and preview the site utilizing the `blogdown::serve_site()` command. This is the easiest way I know of previewing static HTML sites. Utilizing [hugo](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo) *R Studio* coerces my browser to go to the `127.0.0.1:XXXX` location and my local site is previewed before my eyes.

**Can I serve local sites natively with Ubuntu 18.04? How?** I imagine it should be very simple. Searching online I can't find any simple way to do it though. If I simply open the static HTML files directly in my browser they showup wonky. All image links are immediately broken. Formatting of headings, hyperlinks, etc is not the same as when I serve the page locally with [hugo](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo).

***EDIT*** - I did not really define my term 'simplicity'. There are two different approaches (so far) in the answers, one that is simplest to the end user, and one that is simple with regard to operations being performed by my computer. I like both approaches and will welcome answers utilizing any approach as I test them. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'wonky'. When I open static HTML from a file, it shows up the way I expect.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen To be fair, neither of those are a good match for the "simplest HTTP local server". There are plenty of far more lightweight / simple options available.

Comment: I support @user535733. You should investigate why the webpages are not displaying properly without a server, because those problems will inform what solution you need. Perhaps the pages contain URLs ("http://") to local files? In that case you need a server, or you change the URLs to relative paths and make sure the files exist relative to the viewed document. This implies that you need the whole web site file tree locally.

Comment: @Peter A. Schneider I drag my `index.html` file onto Chrome and this is the url `file:///C:/Users/jason/hugoweb/public/index.html` in my address bar. All image links are immediately broken. And formatting of headings, hyperlinks, etc is not the same as when I serve the page locally with hugo. Why, I have no idea?!? I'm open to answers.

Comment: if you have npm globally, install http-server globaly, then you can do in any directory in your terminal http-server to serve the files in localhost. (Default port 8080 but use -p to configure the port).

Comment: Maybe we can remove the R part of the question, as R is not at all related to the question?

Comment: if you have node in your system, run this:
npm install http-server -g
then on terminal use http-server
a simple way for ever

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Ubuntu ships using python3 as its default, and they have gone to great lengths to make this extremely easy for us :D

To start the http server on port *port* simply type

```
python -m http.server port
```

If you want to share files and dirs,  cd into whichever directory you want to serve

```
cd /my/html/files
python -m http.server 8080
```

Should you want to use an address other than the default `0.0.0.0` you can use `--bind`

Ex: `python -m http.server 8080 --bind 127.0.0.1` will serve them at the address `127.0.0.1:8080` :)

Edit: Whether or not it truly was great lengths, I'll leave that to the reader

Also for your convenience here is a link to the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html

Comment: Is the port the *`XXXX`* in `127.0.0.1:XXXX` or is it the entire string `127.0.0.1:XXXX`?

Comment: It will just be the `XXXX` but by default it will serve at `0.0.0.0:port` I will update my answer to reflect how to bind to a different address

Comment: If you are using a very old ubuntu release: in python2 the module is called `SimpleHTTPServer`. note however that it always binds to `0.0.0.0` you can only choose the port, thus use it *exclusively* if you are in a secure network.

Comment: Note you need a wrapper in case it crashes.

Comment: How do you stop those servers after usage?

Comment: In pithon 2.7 the command is `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`

Comment: @KFleischer Enter Ctrl-C, or use the kill command

Comment: This is very useful

Comment: When I try this, firefox can't load `.js` files located in subdirectories and included in the parent document using a relative path. The specific error is a 404, suggesting python won't serve files in subdirectories by default?

Answer (score 65):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255) is a list of HTTP server in one line. I am sure there is one that will fit your purposes/existing tooling.

Hereafter is a subset of the link, that contains in my opinion the most convenient ones.

Python:

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

Ruby:

```
ruby -run -ehttpd . -p8000
```

Node:

```
npm install -g http-server
http-server -p 8000
```

Php:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Comment: Nice answer. It provides information about many different options.

Comment: In python 2.7 the command is: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

Comment: I strongly recommend the Node option (http-server). It is the most feature-rich one, supporting partial downloads and more, which is great if you are streaming videos for instance.

Comment: @BoraM.Alper if you need specific features, maybe you shouldn't look for a simple http server, but rather configure one to fit your needs.

Answer (score 9):

One simple way to setup a **static http site** is to use [darkhttpd](https://unix4lyfe.org/darkhttpd/)

There is no package in ubuntu for that but the software is just one single source file that you can download with a tarball on the site or with git :

```
git clone https://unix4lyfe.org/git/darkhttpd
cd darkhttpd
```

Then run  `make` and you have your *darkhttpd* executable. (Place it in `/usr/local/bin` to make it available to every user)

Run

```
./darkhttpd /path/to/wwwroot
```

or

```
./darkhttpd --help
```

to get help about the command

One can specify directory or port to use and many other options.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apt install apache2` will install the apache2 webserver. By default it provides access to `index.html` in the `/var/www/html` folder; replacing this file with whatever you want to host is the easiest way to do things, then you can navigate to http://127.0.0.1 on your local machine, or to your machine's IP address on your network and it will serve the pages.

Comment: after I install apache2 do I need to initiate the program with an `apache2` command from the command line? Or does it run continuously in the background? I'd prefer not to run it continuously in the background.

Comment: you can turn it on/off/enable at startup by running (respectively) `sudo systemctl start apache2` `sudo systemctl stop apache2` `sudo systemctl enable apache2`. by default it does not run at startup, but does run after installation. If you change index.html while it is running, it will just serve the new version without needing a restart.

Comment: `apache2` is way overkill for just a simple static site.

Comment: I get the impression that simplicity and speed are the goal more than the weight of the program.

Comment: @Minty yes and OP has also to deal with permissions and stuff with Apache. The Python HTTP server solution is much simpler. Yours would be needed if the site was PHP based. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are a Google Chrome user, it can be as easy as using the [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en).  Simply install it, launch it, click **Choose Folder** to select the directory that holds your static files.

Comment: This is a super underrated way of doing it

Comment: is there anything like this for firefox?

Comment: Meanwhile, there is also a [native app](https://simplewebserver.org/).

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to remember the python command's arguments, use **woof**:

```
Description: share files through HTTP protocol
 Woof (Web Offer One File) is a tool to copy files among hosts. It can serve a
 specified file on HTTP, just for a given number of times, and then exits.

Features include:
 * it can share stuff "one shot" and exit just after he served that file.
 * it can share things among different operating system or different devices
   (e.g.: a smartphone), and allows one to upload files easily.
 * it can also show a simple html form in order to upload file (useful if the
   client hasn't a way to serve the file).
```

You can install it on Debian/Ubuntu with

```
apt install woof
```

And use as

```
woof kittens.png
```

It will print an URL to put into a browser at the other end.

Comment: wow so easy, upload and download

Comment: Unfortunately, woof doesn't seem to be included in Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest (and the most limited) solutions would be using `netcat` as described in [this article](https://fabianlee.org/2016/09/26/ubuntu-simulating-a-web-server-using-netcat/):

`while true; do { echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n$(date)\r\n\r\n<h1>hello world from $(hostname) on $(date)</h1>" |  nc -vl 8080; } done`

This example is serving on port 8080, serving on first 1024 ports will require you to use `sudo`. You can also serve a file this way simply by using `cat filename`.

For a more complicated example check out [bashttpd](https://github.com/avleen/bashttpd).

Also note the differences between [netcat-traditional](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/nc.traditional.1.html) and [netcat-openbsd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/nc_openbsd.1.html). Ubuntu provides both versions.